# iOS16 remove the separator line of navigation bar in swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

[image]

I'm not able to remove the separator line for the navigation stack. It works if it is dark mode and you cant see the separator but when it is `Color.white` the line is visible. Tried setting background image and adding attributes, setting background colour but none of these are working.

See code below. Can anyone see any issues?

```
NavigationStack {
     VStack {
       Text("hi")         
     }
     .background(currentUserColorScheme == .dark ? Color.red: Color.white)
     .toolbarBackground(currentUserColorScheme == .dark ? Color.red : Color.white, for: .navigationBar)
     .navigationTitle("Title")
     .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
}
```

Comment: Can you share what your `ListSection` looks like?

Comment: it's just some text, I updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use UIKit APIs and make it happen like:

```
.onAppear { UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = .init() }
```

Comment: this doesn't work unless I have done something incorrect. where should the `onAppear` be added? to the `NavigationStack`

Comment: won't that remove it globally?

Comment: Yes, but you can make it appear again in `onDissappear` @alionthego

Comment: And also you can add a line with a simple `divider` where ever you want to have a full control on it